# INSERT INTO - errors, but allows input into table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

For reasons I cannot see I get the following error message:

*Compile error: Method or data member not found*

when I use the following:

```
Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = " INSERT INTO BERTHAGE " _
& "(BOAT, LOCATION, BERTH_WEEK, BERTH_YEAR, BERTHED) VALUES " _
    & Me.Add_Boat & "','" _
    & Me.LOCATION & "','" _
    & Me.txt_week & "','" _
    & Me.txt_year & "','" _
    & Me.In_Port & "');"

cmd_Clear_Click

End Sub
```

Once I click OK and use the refresh button the entry is put into the database, but each time I do an entry I have to go to the same process.

I would like to figure out what method or data is missing?

I should add that there is an outnumber primary key field on this table (Berth_ID), and each time I use the cmd_Add button a new ID number is created for the new record.  This includes creating a new ID number for the new record that triggers the error.

Here is all the VBA associated with this form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
End Sub

Private Sub LOCATION_Change()
    Me.txt_Cur_Flo = Me.LOCATION.Column(1)
    Me.txt_Cur_Doc = Me.LOCATION.Column(2)
    Me.txt_Cur_Ori = Me.LOCATION.Column(3)
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = " INSERT INTO BERTHAGE " _
& "(BOAT, LOCATION, BERTH_WEEK, BERTH_YEAR, BERTHED) VALUES " _
    & Me.Add_Boat & "','" _
    & Me.LOCATION & "','" _
    & Me.txt_week & "','" _
    & Me.txt_year & "','" _
    & Me.In_Port & "');"

cmd_Clear_Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Clear_Click()
Me.Add_Boat = ""
Me.LOCATION = ""
Me.txt_Cur_Flo = ""
Me.txt_Cur_Doc = ""
Me.txt_Cur_Ori = ""  
Me.Add_Boat.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Close_Click()
DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting a compile error, or a runtime error?  If you compile the project in the VB editor what do you see?

Comment: What does Access highlight when it gives you the compile error?

Comment: @TimWilliams Compile Error- method or data not found

Comment: @HansUp it highlights .LOCATION from me.LOCATION &

Comment: I will say no as LOCATION appears to 'know' the numbered spot I am trying to use, eg, I choose location 6 on the form and when I run cmd_Add_Click  I get the following in the immediate window Debug.Print Me.LOCATION
 6

Answer (score 2):

Consider the best practice of [parameterization](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and not string concatenation of SQL mixed with VBA variables. Due to missing quotes, the compiler attempts to reference a column name and not its literal value. Instead, consider parameterization with defined types which is supported with Access SQL using [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao). Notice below, SQL and VBA are complete separate.

**SQL** *(save as stored query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS prmBoat TEXT, prmLoc INT, prmBerthed INT;
INSERT INTO BERTHAGE (BOAT, LOCATION, BERTHED)
VALUES(prmBoat, prmLoc, prmBerthed)
```

**VBA**

```vb
Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedParamQuery")

' BIND PARAM VALUES
qdef!prmBoat = Me.Add_Boat
qdef!prmLoc = Me.LOCATION
qdef!prmBerthed = Me.In_Port

' EXECUTE ACTION QUERY
qdef.Execute

Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

---

Even better, save your query with form controls intact and simply call [OpenQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery):

**SQL** *(save as stored query)*

```sql
INSERT INTO BERTHAGE(BOAT, LOCATION, BERTHED)
VALUES(Forms!myForm!Add_Boat, Forms!myForm!LOCATION, Forms!myForm!In_Port)
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String

   DoCmd.SetWarnings False                   ' TURN OFF APPEND PROMPTS
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedActionQuery"
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True                    ' RESET WARNINGS

   Call cmd_Clear_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: I will consider it, but I'm just not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

Missing opening parenthesis after `VALUES`. Also missing apostrophe in front of `Me.Add_Boat`. These special characters must always be in pairs, an even number by counting.

If Berth_Week and Berth_Year are number fields (and should be), don't use apostrophe delimiters.

If In_Port is a Yes/No field, don't use apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: I believe this is what you are suggesting  Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = " INSERT INTO BERTHAGE " & "(BOAT, LOCATION, BERTH_WEEK, BERTH_YEAR, BERTHED) VALUES ("
        ' & Me.Add_Boat & "','" _
        & Me.LOCATION & "'," _
        & Me.txt_week & "," _
        & Me.txt_year & "," _
        & Me.In_Port & ");"

    cmd_Clear_Click

End Sub    The issue I find is when I use the ' it greens out the rest of the lines behind it?

Comment: Put apostrophe inside quote marks same as others, so `VALUES('" & `

Comment: Still same issue - the line Private Sub cmd_Add_Click() highlights yellow and then .LOCATION in the line & Me.LOCATION & "'," _ highlights blue background with white letters, after I hit the stop button and refresh the entry goes into the table correctly.

Comment: Access is not recognizing name LOCATION. Me.LOCATION is a listbox?

Comment: it is a combo box

Comment: Try renaming combobox. I name controls different from field and like to use prefixes, tbxBoat, cbxLoc, chkPort, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214687/discussion-between-dhpa-and-june7).

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that I was doubling up the inputs into the 'week' and 'year' field.  this was happening (I believe) because those text box fields were already accessing the week and year information directly from the default value on the BERTHAGE table.  Essentially I went through each input and would run it individually waiting for the error to occur.  Once it occurred I took it out of the INSERT INFO statement. With the removal of week and year, everything is working.  That was a painful exercise, and still not complete, but I am back to a function form/DB so I'll take the small victories when they occur.

```
Private Sub cmd_Add_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO BERTHAGE " & "(BOAT, LOCATION, BERTHED) VALUES ('" &     Me.Add_Boat & "'," _
    & Me.New_Loc & "," _
    & Me.In_Port & ");"

cmd_Clear_Click

DoCmd.Requery

End Sub`
```

Comment: Glad you found your solution. However, I would be remiss not to emphasize again parameterization and avoid messy string concatenation of SQL. This is a programming industry concept for *any* language beyond VBA that interacts with *any* database beyond Access using SQL. I know you want the *easy* answer that works (which arguably is the `DoCmd.OpenQuery` approach) but you would be thankful in future to heed best practices for readable, maintainable, efficient code. Good luck and happy coding!